# Why does this return 0?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace test_warmup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int test = -1110835200;
            test = test * 1700397056;
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`-1110835200 * 1700397056 = -1888860903781171200`

Displayed in hex, that's `-0x1a3694fc_00000000`

In C#, [`int` is only 32-bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table), so the result is truncated to just `0`.

In other words, the result of that multiplication is too large to fit in the variable to which you're assigning it, and the part that fits is all zero.

Comment: You can demonstrate this difference by simply changing the type to a long. `long test = -1110835200;`